# SQL LIKE in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to implement a join in Spark SQL using a LIKE condition.

The row I am performing the join on looks like this and is called 'revision':

Table A:

```
8NXDPVAE
```

Table B:

```
[4,8]NXD_V%
```

Performing the join on SQL server (`A.revision LIKE B.revision`) works just fine, but when doing the same in Spark SQL, the join returns no rows (if using inner join) or null values for Table B (if using outer join).

This is the query I am running:

```
val joined = spark.sql("SELECT A.revision, B.revision FROM RAWDATA A LEFT JOIN TPTYPE B ON A.revision LIKE B.revision")
```

The plan looks like this:

```
== Physical Plan ==
BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, LeftOuter, revision#15 LIKE revision#282, false
:- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
:  +- *Project [revision#15]
:     +- *Scan JDBCRelation(RAWDATA) [revision#15] PushedFilters: [EqualTo(bulk_id,2016092419270100198)], ReadSchema: struct<revision>
+- *Scan JDBCRelation(TPTYPE) [revision#282] ReadSchema: struct<revision>
```

Is it possible to perform a LIKE join like this or am I way off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are only a little bit off. Spark SQL and Hive follow SQL standard conventions where `LIKE` operator accepts only two special characters:

- `_` (underscore) - which matches an arbitrary character.
- `%` (percent) - which matches an arbitrary sequence of characters.

Square brackets have no special meaning and `[4,8]` matches only a `[4,8]` literal:

```
spark.sql("SELECT '[4,8]' LIKE '[4,8]'").show
```

```
+----------------+
|[4,8] LIKE [4,8]|
+----------------+
|            true|
+----------------+
```

To match complex patterns you can use `RLIKE` operator which suports Java regular expressions:

```
spark.sql("SELECT '8NXDPVAE' RLIKE '^[4,8]NXD.V.*$'").show
```

```
+-----------------------------+
|8NXDPVAE RLIKE ^[4,8]NXD.V.*$|
+-----------------------------+
|                         true|
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

Syntax for like in spark scala api:

```
dataframe.filter(col("columns_name").like("regex"))
```