# Hive - Create table LIKE doesn't work in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my pyspark job I'm trying to create a temp table using LIKE clause as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stg.new_table_name LIKE stg.exiting_table_name LOCATION s3://s3-bucket/warehouse/stg/existing_table_name
```

My job fails as below -

> mismatched input 'LIKE' expecting (line 1, pos 56)\n\n== SQL
>   ==\nCREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stg.new_table_name LIKE
>   stg.exiting_table_name LOCATION
>   s3://s3-bucket/warehouse/stg/existing_table_name

**Doesn't spark support `LIKE` clause to create new table using metadata of existing table?**

My sparksession config:

```
self.session = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName(self.app_name) \
            .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false") \
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
            .config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2") \
            .config("hive.load.dynamic.partitions.thread", "10") \
            .config("hive.mv.files.thread", "30") \
            .config("fs.trash.interval", "0") \
            .enableHiveSupport()
```

Comment: Yes, I did enable the hive support

Comment: maybe this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454262/sql-like-in-spark-sql

Comment: Issue in that link is different.